# xcode objective c CAShapelayer

Tags: objective-c, math, cashapelayer

[image]

i have draw a circle with CAShapelayer,and now i want to draw a triangle on the path from the circle an pointed to the center of the circle.Can someone help me to find out the A,B and C points?

```
   CAShapeLayer *circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
   [circleLayer setPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100)] CGPath]];
   [circleLayer setStrokeColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
   [circleLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
   circleLayer.lineWidth=5;
   [[self.view layer] addSublayer:circleLayer];
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as c#?

Comment: this is a maths question, not a programming question